# Comparison of Date and Time

Tags: android, string, date, time, comparison

I have to get count of days which are past to the current day.I have list of days in arraylist.I got the list and I dont know how to compare?Can anyone help me?

This is the code I tried,

```
private void weeklylogeval(){
    int i;
DateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
dateFormatter.setLenient(false);
Date today = new Date();
String s = dateFormatter.format(today);
System.out.println("current date & time new:::"+s);
for(i=0;i<datetime.size();i++){
String daytime=datetime.get(i);
if(today.before(daytime))
}
}
```

Pls some one help me!

Comment: Do you just wish to calculate the difference between days?

Comment: I got the arraylist from my mysql database where the difference between days are already calculated in php.Now I want to compare my current date and time with arraylist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code for date difference manipulation.

```
String fd=from_date;//date get from mysql database as string.
String td=to_date;//Today's date as string.
if(!fd.equalsIgnoreCase("") && !td.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
       SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
           SimpleDateFormat formatter;
           Date frmdt=new Date(fd);
           formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
           String s1 = formatter.format(frmdt);
           Date todt=new Date(td);
           String s2 = formatter.format(todt);
           Date frmdate = sdf.parse(s1);
           Date todate = sdf.parse(s2);
                  if(frmdate.compareTo(todate)<=0) {
                                //do your stuff
                     } else {
                                // do your stuff
                     }
             }
```

Comment: how can I get the value for td? i.e., today date as string?

Comment: @Jolly     SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                   Date date = new Date();     
      String td = sdf.format(date);

Comment: @Jolly Change the SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy") as you need.Like date with time or only date or only time.

Comment: @Ram...No it not works for me.It asks me to change frmdt and todt to string

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html

This should be allot easier to use for your purpose
Edit:

Methods you can use:

boolean  after(Object calendar)
Returns whether the Date represented by this Calendar instance is after the Date represented by the parameter.
boolean  before(Object calendar)
Returns whether the Date represented by this Calendar instance is before the Date represented by the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can construct a Date form the String you get from DB, and then use `today.before(daytime)` to compare them.

```
Date daytime = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss").parse(datetime.get(i));
```